# Error: unexpected symbol/input/string constant/numeric constant/SPECIAL in my R

Tags: r

I am praticing R codes. When I type

```
euclidean = matrix(0, nrow=51, ncol=51)
for(i in 2:52)
  {for(j in 2:52)
{euclidean[i,j]=sqrt((u[i]-u[j]^2 + (v[i]-v[j]^2)}}
```

It gives me errors:

> Error: unexpected '}' in:
> "  {for(j in 2:52)
> {euclidean[i,j]=sqrt((u[i]-u[j]^2 + (v[i]-v[j]^2)}"

How to solve this?

Comment: What are objects `u` and `v`?

Comment: there are unmatched parenthesis within the `sqrt` call.    (note that `(v[i]-v[j]^2` is not the same as `(v[i]-v[j])^2`)

Answer (score 0):

`Error: unexpected '}'` is an indicator of an incorrect syntax. It's often raised by missing or messed up nested parentheses, as in your code example.
Also take care to break up consecutive instructions, as in:

```
euclidean = matrix(0, nrow=51, ncol=51) for(i in 2:52)
```

by new lines (or, if must be, by `;`):

```
euclidean = matrix(0, nrow=51, ncol=51)
for(i in 2:52){...}
```

Any dedicated [programming editor](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5345/ide-alternatives-for-r-programming-rstudio-intellij-idea-eclipse-visual-stud) will help avoid such mistakes with e.g. syntax highlighting, code indentation etc.

When practising R, it is useful to get familiar with those language features which in most cases offer a more concise/readable/faster alternative to `for`-loops: `apply`-like functions, vectorised functions, `Map`ping and `Reduce`ing etc.

E.g., your quadratic euclidean matrix could be generated* with:

```
sqrt(
  outer(u, u, FUN = \(i, j) (i - j)^2) +
  outer(v, v, FUN = \(i, j) (i - j)^2)
)
```

(there's also a specific function `dist` for distance matrices)

* replacing a-b<sup>2</sup> square of your original formula with (a-b)<sup>2</sup>: the former would yield negative values and an error upon `sqrt`, the latter being used for euclidean distances.